# wp_remote_post not sending post data

Tags: php, json, forms, api, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to send form data. The form is on all the posts of a particular post type. So I have filtered the post Ids to send form data of that particular post id form. Am using wp remote post, still, it is not sending the data to the client URL. Below is the code

```
$posts = get_posts( array(    'include'   => '3,8,1,17',
    'post_type' => 'property'
    
) );

If($posts) {
function myUni(){

$name = sanitize_text_field($POST['name']);
$email = sanitize_email($POST['email']);
$mobile = sanitize_text_field($POST['mobile']);


$token ='bearer token goes here' ;


$body = array(
'firstName' => '$name',
'email' => '$email',
'mobilePhone' => '$mobile', 
'Comment' => 'Lead from website ' 
);

$url = 'https://server7.farvisioncloud.com/SFA/odata/LeadListSave'; 

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array
(
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
'Authorization' => 'Bearer'. $token
),
    'body' => $body,
    'cookies' => array()
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Body should be JSON data, you can try "wp_json_encode".

> > $body = wp_json_encode( $body );